# Looking for an email client for EWS

Tags: 20.04, email, evolution, email-client

Can anyone recommend me a mail client solution for Ubuntu that works well with EWS? the best thing I tried was Evolution with Evolution-EWS, but still I can't do some stuff like see my groups and my groups' emails and calendars

Comment: What is EWS? Please explain briefly.

Comment: Exchange Web Services, basically I want some alternative for Ubuntu that does everything an Outlook client would do on Windows.

Comment: OK, would be good to edit that question so people immediately know what this abbreviation refers to,